# Git merging master to branch - conflicts (coming from Subversion background)

Tags: git, svn, github, version-control, merge

**Subversion Background:**

We are transitioning from `Subversion` to `Git`.

We used `Subversion trunk` to be our "gold copy", create long-running feature branches, and we would merge `trunk` to branch many times.

Finally when the feature was complete, we would merge the branch back into `trunk`.

When we did this, if `Bar.java` was modified in `trunk`, but we never modified it in the branch, we would never get merge conflicts on `Bar.java`.

I believe this is because `Subversion` has a concept of `svn:mergeinfo`, and knows about the history of the merges and that `Bar.java` was never modified in the branch.

**SVN Branch Maintenence Diagram:**

[image: SVN Branch Maintenence Diagram]

**Git Behavior:**

Now that we have transitioned to `Git`, we are getting conflicts on merging master to the branch, even if we did not change `Bar.java` in the branch!

I believe this is because Git does not have the same notion of `svn:mergeinfo` and does not keep track of the fact that `Bar.java` changes came over from `master` and were merged in.

**Git Diagram (SHOWS ISSUE):**

[image: Git Diagram (SHOWS ISSUE)]

**Question:**

Is there any way we can continue using the same approach we used in `Subversion` (frequent merges of trunk to branch) without getting conflicts in `Git`?

Is there a way to implement an equivalent of `svn:mergeinfo` so that Git knows that a file only changed in `master` and never changed in `branch`, and merge automatically?

**Although the example I illustrated is trivial (one file), realistically we have numerous developers working in parallel and end up dealing with numerous files conflicting, and this difference in behavior from `svn` to `git` is causing us a lot of pain.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git does have analogue to `svn:mergeinfo`, in fact a much more advanced one. If you see merge conflicts on files you haven't touched in your branch that means either you did touch it somehow (automatic line endings conversion by IDE is a common pitfall), or somewhat has rewritten the history on trunk. Make sure that you guys don't do `git rebase`, `commit --amend` or similar history rewriting changes against the trunk ever.

*Edit as for how do we search for mergeinfo*

Standard `git log` would show you the merge info at the second line:

```
$ git log
commit 1ca56fefd6ed1af2a6e62f1fbd811d56fa72ded7 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Merge: a3323f6 2237297
```

Normally you use graphical representation at UI to see what has been merged and what not. At the command line `git log --oneline --graph HEAD origin/master` would show a subgraph containing your current workdir and `origin/master` for examination. `git log origin/master --not HEAD` would print you the commits that git assumes not yet merged from master to you current branch.

Comment: Thanks very much! Is there a way to view the Git equivalent of `svn:mergeinfo`?  I'll try cutting a clean Git repo and experimenting ... we do have a LOT of developers new to Git and everyone using different Git Clients, so i can't say for sure if someone did a `rebase` or anything that modified history on master.

Comment: Thank you, I accept your answer, confirmed everything is correct that you provided regarding the mergeinfo when working off a clean Git Repo.  We must be doing something wrong within our team regarding different git clients or perhaps line endings or tabs v spaces.